# Why is Husky pre-commit hook failing on Windows?

Tags: bash, git, npm, husky

On Windows, Husky pre-commit hooks fail with the following error message:

```
/usr/bin/env: 'bash': No such file or directory
husky - pre-commit hook exited with code 127 (error)
husky - command not found in PATH=/mingw64/libexec/git-core:/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/cmd:/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin
```

However my commit hook only runs a `npm` command that does not involve bash. Why is this command looking for `bash` and failing to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Husky hooks are executed with `sh` rather than `cmd`, even on Windows.
If the hook contains a `npm` command, it will try to execute `npm.sh` (e.g. `C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm`) rather than `npm.cmd` from the same folder.

This `C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm` script relies on bash, as shown in the shebang line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

If you are using a stripped down installation of Git that does not include `bash` such as [MinGit](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/wiki/MinGit) (widely used in CI), you might get the error above. In this case, you might want to use the complete Git for Windows to include `bash`. Else you need to modify your Git hooks to be Windows-compliant.